# Responsive grid with one element being fixed (relative to the first element in the grid)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a horizontal banner that I would like to keep right below the large square (top-left corner in the grid, see Fig. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGeu3.png)). This means, that in the grid, I will have 1(large)+6(regular) grid elements, before I have the banner.

[image: No zoom]

In case one zooms in on the page, or views it on a smaller resolution, I would like to keep the horizontal banner right below the large square, as seen in Fig. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKuJS.png).

[image: Some zoom]

And, if a user uses a resolution that can fit only the large square across, and no regular squares - then I would like to place all regular squares right after the banner, as seen in Fig. [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCwPL.png).

How can I achieve this?

I use Bootstrap 3 and Angular.

Thank you very much.

[image: Max zoom]

Comment: You should take a look at [intention.js](http://intentionjs.com/). It automatically "reoders" your DOM depending on the users viewport

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem like yours recently.

The *big box* and the *small boxes* need to be separated by 2 elements(I use div).

So, you have `div>big_box` + `div>small_box*6`. This way, you can easily change the width.

Using this classes:

> **col-lg-** stands for width **>= 1200px**
>   **col-md-** stands for width **>= 992px**
>   **col-sm-** stands for width **>= 768px**
>   **col-xs-** stands for width **< 768px**

Knowing the sizes, you need to understand that Bootstrap separates the blocks in 12 parts.
So, using your first example, it looks like it's 4 or 5 for the big_box, and 8 or 7 for the small_boxes.

So it would look like:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="big_box"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="small_box"></div>
    ...
    <div class="small_box"></div>
</div>
```

As for box sizes, or which block you should hide, it would be better to be by your choise using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)